# How to know if, Android MediaPlayer buffering has stopped deliberately(not because of network issue) because enough buffering has done already

Tags: android, c++, http, media-player, android-mediaplayer

Using MediaPlayer.OnInfoListener I am able to see when MediaPlayer is temporarily pausing playback internally in order to buffer more data.

But as MediaPlayer obeys progressive HTTP download, Ideally it pauses buffering since enough buffering is already done, If user continues to 
watch video it will buffer next chunk of data.

I want to know exactly when buffering has stopped because enough buffering is done. (not because network issues, congestion, low bandwidth etc.)

Am I thinking it in wrong way?
If not, Is there any way to find this?